# mount to an existing ubuntu server os

Tags: partitioning, mountpoint

I currently have ubuntu server installed on an ext4 partition which contains the root file system. I wanted to separate /var out to its own partition. So I booted gparted live, created another ext4 partition and then booted ubuntu server, and selected that partition and selected /var as the mount point of that partition. But when I selected "finish partitioning and write changes to disc", I get a red screen that says "No root filesystem is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu". But I don't want this partition to have a root file system. I just want the sda1 root file system with os installed to use /var from this partition.

Comment: have you tried that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Ubuntu use that partition (supposing it is `sda2`) as `/var` you just need to add that mount point in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2   /var    ext4    defaults    0   2
```

If you want you can use also the UUID of the partition: just do `la -la /dev/disk/by-uuid` and get the correct value for sda2:

```
UUID=<uuid-for-sda2>    /var    ext4    defaults    0   2
```

Finally reboot or use `sudo mount -a`.

NOTE: you will have to move/copy the actual contents of `/var` to the new partition.